# ADALiOS Custom Login Screen

Tags: objective-c, authentication, office365, adal

I'm using Azure Office 365 authentication in my iOS app. Everything is working fine, but in the ADALiOS framework is there any way I can override the WebView login screen with a custom login screen and then authenticate using the Username and Password from that screen?

I don't mind digging into the framework and customizing, just wondering if its even possible and if someone more familiar with the framework could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am from the ADAL dev team.
You should be able to customize the branding of the application with your custom logo and name in Azure Portal and thats the only customization allowed.

Comment: Just so i understand you correctly, using the ADAL framework, there is not a way to pass in a username and password and have all the authentication done without bringing up the webview?

Comment: I don't want to customize the webview,..i dont want to use the webview at all

Comment: Yes, you are correct. What you are looking for is called Resource owner password grant and it is not currently supported in the API.

Comment: KanishkPanwar, Can we create a custom webview ?   ADAuthenticationContext has webView  :           /*Gets or sets the webview, which will be used for the credentials. If nil, the library will create a webview object
 when needed, leveraging the parentController property. \*/
@property (weak) WebViewType* webView;

Comment: yes, you can. The property is available to be set in AuthenticationContext

Comment: @KanishkPanwar-MSFT Hi, do you have any sample code in swift for using Office365 ios SDK and access the sharepoint lists functionality?